# 1 Table, 2 Column (int, varchar), 1 NEW Key as int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Could use your help on this.

I have a table with 2 columns like this:

```
Column 1 |        Column 2
---------+--------------------
 1       | (         1,  1,1)
 2       | (        45,  2,9)
 3       | (      4456, 98,0)
 4       | (    196416,511,1)
97       | (   3213658, 45,7)
98       | (      2315,  6,7)
99       | (9999999999,999,9)
```

AS definition:

- Column 1:         max  2 characters
- Column 2 - Part 1 max 10 characters
- Column 2 - Part 2 max  3 characters
- Column 2 - Part 3 max  1 characters

So the key has to be at least 16 characters long.

In the end I need help in creating the key for column 3 as int - looking like this:

```
Column 1 |        Column 2    |  Column 3 - Key
---------+--------------------+------------------
 1       | (         1,  1,1) | 0100000000010011
 2       | (        45,  2,9) | 0200000000450029
 3       | (      4456, 98,0) | 0300000044560980
 4       | (    196416,511,1) | 0400001964165111
97       | (   3213658, 45,7) | 9700032136580457
98       | (      2315,  6,7) | 9800000023150067
99       | (9999999999,999,9) | 9999999999999999
```

Would appreciate your help.

Thanks and Regards,

Erik

Comment: If you only need to update it just looks at the functions REPLICATE, LEN and SUBSTRING, with these three you should be able to form the third column

Comment: You can use [`cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get `[Column 1]` as a string, [`replicate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to build strings of zeroes, [`substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to pull pieces out of `[Column 2]`, [`right`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the zero-filled values.

Comment: Start with `Right( Replicate( '0', 2 ) + Cast( [Column 1] as VarChar(2) ), 2 )` and go from there.

Comment: The title says "NEW Key as int". If you really want an [`Int`] then you need to know that (1) it doesn't have leading zeroes and (b) the range is -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647). A `BigInt` would address (b). A `Char(16)` takes care of both.

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Comment: Hi Zohar, the delimited column can't be replaced. A tool from a service provider creates the table and the column this way. There is no way to have any influence on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were told already, that this storage is NOT recommended. Rather use 3 separate columns for this and compute the needed value *on the fly* when needed.

As this seems to be padded correctly it might be as simple as this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Column1 INT, Column2 VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES   
 ( 1,'(         1,  1,1)')
,( 2,'(        45,  2,9)')
,( 3,'(      4456, 98,0)')
,( 4,'(    196416,511,1)')
,(97,'(   3213658, 45,7)')
,(98,'(      2315,  6,7)')
,(99,'(9999999999,999,9)');

SELECT *
      ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Column2,' ','0'),',',''),'(',''),')','')
FROM @tbl t;
```

Alternatively you can split this `Column 2` and deal with the values separately:

--using the JSON-splitting here (needs v2016+)
--Below v2016 there are various splitting approaches (XML based, Jeff Moden's function and many more...)

```
SELECT t.*
      ,A.*
      ,CONCAT(REPLACE(STR(A.val1,10),' ','0')
             ,REPLACE(STR(A.val2, 3),' ','0')
             ,REPLACE(STR(A.val3, 1),' ','0')) AS [new key]
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Column2,'(','[['),')',']]'))
            WITH(val1 BIGINT '$[0]'
                ,val2 BIGINT '$[1]'
                ,val3 BIGINT '$[2]') A;
```

The result

```
+---------+--------------------+------------+------+------+--------------------+
| Column1 | Column2            | val1       | val2 | val3 | new key            |
+---------+--------------------+------------+------+------+--------------------+
| 1       | (         1,  1,1) | 1          | 1    | 1    | 00000000010011     |
+---------+--------------------+------------+------+------+--------------------+
| 2       | (        45,  2,9) | 45         | 2    | 9    | 00000000450029     |
+---------+--------------------+------------+------+------+--------------------+
| 3       | (      4456, 98,0) | 4456       | 98   | 0    | 00000044560980     |
+---------+--------------------+------------+------+------+--------------------+
| 4       | (    196416,511,1) | 196416     | 511  | 1    | 00001964165111     |
+---------+--------------------+------------+------+------+--------------------+
| 97      | (   3213658, 45,7) | 3213658    | 45   | 7    | 00032136580457     |
+---------+--------------------+------------+------+------+--------------------+
| 98      | (      2315,  6,7) | 2315       | 6    | 7    | 00000023150067     |
+---------+--------------------+------------+------+------+--------------------+
| 99      | (9999999999,999,9) | 9999999999 | 999  | 9    | 99999999999999     |
+---------+--------------------+------------+------+------+--------------------+
```

**update** if below v2016

Before JSON one often used hack was something along this:

```
SELECT t.*
      ,A.*
      ,CONCAT(REPLACE(STR(A.AsXml.value('/x[1]','bigint'),10),' ','0')
             ,REPLACE(STR(A.AsXml.value('/x[2]','bigint'), 3),' ','0')
             ,REPLACE(STR(A.AsXml.value('/x[3]','bigint'), 1),' ','0')) AS [new key]
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Column2,',','</x><x>'),'(','<x>'),')','</x>') AS XML)) A(AsXml);
```

Hint: In any case the result is a string and not a number. Otherwise you would not keep the leading zeros... But you might use `CAST(... AS BIGINT)` to achieve a key as (big) integer number.